# creating an interval timer reset

Tags: javascript, angularjs, timer

I am have a slight problem with the `interval`delay offset for my slide when i click to view another slide.

For example.. I have 10 slides with slide identifiers visible, slide 1 is visible with a pause delay of 5secs, i click on the 5th thumbnail/identifier the slider will showcase the 5th slide however the delay offset for the timer will only be what was remaining of the 5secs from the initial slide.

Is there a way i can add a timer reset or pause to my function. [Plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/7ju6keOTWIdP8cCU3c11?p=preview)

```
$scope.startAuto = function() {
    var timer = $interval(function() {

    if ($scope.jobNotification < $scope.jobs.length -1) {
      $scope.jobNotification += 1;
    } else {
      $scope.jobNotification = 0;

    }

    }, 3000);
};

$scope.isActive = function (index) {
    return $scope.jobNotification === index;
 };

$scope.showJobNotification = function (index) {
    $scope.jobNotification = index;
};
```

Comment: Your plunkr doesn't do anything. And why is it vastly different from what you've posted here? I don't see any `startAuto` there.

Comment: @JLRishe Sorry, wrong Plunkr link, i'll update

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can stop and restart the timer when the page is changed:

```
var timer;
$scope.startAuto = function() {
    timer = $interval(function() {
        $scope.jobNotification = ($scope.jobNotification + 1) % $scope.jobs.length;
    }, 3000);
};

$scope.restartAuto = function () {
    if (timer) {
        $interval.cancel(timer);
    }
    $scope.startAuto();
};

$scope.isActive = function (index) {
    return $scope.jobNotification === index;
};

$scope.showJobNotification = function (index) {
    $scope.restartAuto();
    $scope.jobNotification = index;
};
```